# Why was my answer deleted by a mod and another high-rep user?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

[This post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46096/complete-and-correct-version-of-siddha-kunjika-stotra/57405) that I wrote was deleted:

> [image]

Why was it  deleted? I am new to this website, I just want some information. Please help.

Comment: What are you talking about.? I am not a moderator. I don't delete post. Atleast give a link or something. ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️..

Comment: Here's the link to my original question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46096/complete-and-correct-version-of-siddha-kunjika-stotra/57405?noredirect=1#comment172700_57405  (If I can attach screenshot it will show your username deleted my post)

Comment: I am not sure how to attach screenshot here, my apologies.

Comment: 1st of all that was not a post but a comment. U can't put a comment as an answer. And secondly I don't delete post i can only suggest. Seeing the quality of the post the moderators will decide whether to delete it or not. Check the comment below your post by @Pandya. He is a moderator see the diamond sighn there it indicates a moderator. Don't do anything unnecessary in such a hurry. U can Comment under the question for your query. See this also.: *This post is hidden. It was deleted 3 days ago by Sri Shiva Charañam Dāsa Vishñu, **Pandya♦***.

Comment: Plus, u don't need screen shot u can copy paste it here like i did to show u. In comment pictures can't be pasted only link n texts.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I appreciate it

Comment: U r welcome.....

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of a culture shock for new users on the Stack Exchange network, and that's because, as the [Tour](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) will tell you, "this site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat."

Your 'answer' was not actually an answer, which is why it got deleted. That's just the way this site works.

That would have been better as a *comment* under the main post, which you will be able to do once you reach 50 reputation through asking, answering, and editing. You might also be able to post it as a new [reference-request](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) question.